# \left\right on fraction applies the height of the taller term to both sides - How to make it more compact?

Tags: spacing, pdftex, amsmath, delimiters

In the code below `\left` and `\right` are used to adjust the height of `()` to the nested fraction. While the denominator of the entire fraction is much shorter than that of the numerator, the numerator's height is also applied to the denominator, hanging the denominator in the air. Are there other commands/overrides that make it so that the shorter of the two terms in a fraction does not inherit the height of its longer counterpart?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
$\left(\cfrac{\cfrac{\cfrac{\cfrac{\cfrac{1}{2}+3}{4}+5}{6}+7}{8}+9}{10}\right)$
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Answer (score 2):

The bar of a fraction is vertically centered within the parentheses, even if its numerator is much taller than its denominator. You can circumvent that by placing the fraction in a `\vcenter`, it will then be centered with respect to the height of its numerator plus denominator. However, its bar may then be not aligned with the bars of other fractions in the same formula.

```tex
$\left(\vcenter{\hbox{$\cfrac{\cfrac{\cfrac{\cfrac{\cfrac{1}{2}+3}{4}+5}{6}+7}{8}+9}{10}$}}\right)
+\cfrac12$
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Two suggestions:

- Just omit the `\left(` and `\right)` directives
- use a `pmatrix` environment, essentially treating the `\cfrac` construct as the sole entry in a 1 x 1 matrix.

[image]

The drawback of the `pmatrix`-based and similar solutions is that the main fraction line is no longer based on equation's baseline.

Unless you have a good use case for including the tall parentheses, I think the simplest and best solution is to just omit these parentheses entirely.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for '\cfrac' macro and 'pmatrix' environment
\newcommand\mycfrac{%
  \cfrac{\cfrac{\cfrac{\cfrac{\cfrac{1}{2}+3}{4}+5}{6}+7}{8}+9}{10}}
\begin{document}
\[
\left( \mycfrac \right) % OP's versiion
=
\mycfrac  % just omit the parentheses entirely
=
\begin{pmatrix} \mycfrac \end{pmatrix} % use a pmatrix env.
\]
\end{document}
```